# Pass body_class as a variable to a Gravity forms hidden field

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, gravity

Im using WeGlot to translate my site, and using below snippet to add the current language to my body class:

```
function my_plugin_body_class($classes) {
      unset( $classes[array_search('theme-bz', $classes)] );    
      switch ( weglot_get_current_language() ) {
    case 'nl':
       $classes[] = 'lang-nl';
        break;
    case 'en':
       $classes[] = 'lang-en';
        break;
    case 'de':
        $classes[] = 'lang-de';
        break;
    case 'be':
        $classes[] = 'lang-nl';
        break;
    
    }
    return $classes;
}

add_filter('body_class', 'my_plugin_body_class');
```

On my site I have a Gravity form in my footer for newsletter signups - I have adde da hidden field with the ID of "lang_code"and enabled it to be pre-populated.

How do I pass this class as a variable to be pre-poluated in my hidden field?

This is what I got, not working of course but you get the idea:

```
gravity_form( $formId, false, false, false, array('lang_code' => $classes ), true);
```

Comment: If `weglot_get_current_language()` can be used to get the language … well, then I wonder why you are not using it in that place then?

Comment: @CBroe I tried that as well but I still dont get a value in the form.

Comment: So have you first of all verified that populating the field via code with a _static_ value works?

Comment: @CBROE Ys. Im using this on other Forms. One working example:  

gravity_form(20, false, false, false, ['product_name' => get_the_title(),'product_id' => get_the_ID() ], true);

Comment: It did not mean whether you are using this on other forms, but whether this works for _this_ form, when you supply a static value.

Comment: @CBroe Hmm. I tried to call the product ID the same way I do on another form on a product page.. And Still nothing. So no. It doesnt seems to work with a static value

Comment: I assume I need to somehow declare it as global to be able to access it in the footer, which might be the problem?

Comment: What do you mean, which “it” as global? Where are you calling `gravity_form` right now? `$formId` has to exist in that context of course.